# Vim filetype plugin for gitrebase

Tags: git, vim

I've seen a snippet online for a gitrebase plugin for vim that allows you to easily change between `fixup|squash|pick` etc for git interactive rebase. The post suggests to put the file into a directory called `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` and name it `gitrebase.vim`

I have done all of this but the plugin isn't loaded when I execute `git rebase -i HEAD~x`

What more would I need to do?

The plugin is here incase it is useful for anyone else: https://bloerg.net/2013/12/04/a-tiny-vim-plugin-for-interactive-git-rebasing.html

Comment: Chances are filetype plugins are not enabled. What is the output of `:filetype` during an interactive rebase?

Comment: filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:OFF

Comment: Add `filetype plugin indent on` to your `vimrc`.

Comment: Awesome! Add this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Fun fact! Vim ships with the [`:Cycle`](https://github.com/tpope/vim-git/blob/master/ftplugin/gitrebase.vim) command for `gitrebase` filetype. So all you really need is a mapping in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/gitrebase.vim`. e.g. `nnoremap <buffer> <silent> S :Cycle<CR>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments 2 years ago, you need to enable filetype plugins:

```
filetype plugin on
```

There are other options, like `indent`, that you can enable with this command as well.

However, as mentioned by [@Peter Rincker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438329/peter-rincker), vim ships with a `gitrebase` filetype providing `:Cycle` (as well as `:Pick, Squash, Edit, Reword, Fixup`). You can use it quite effectively.